# Tips and tricks to find remainders

Tags: polynomials, real-numbers

What tips and tricks exist to find remainders?

E.g. what is the remainder when

- $37^{n+2} + 16^{n+1} +30^n$ is divided by 7
- $2^{31}$ by 7
- $1^{2013}$ + $2^{2013}$ + .... + $2012^{2013}$ is divided by 2013

Comment: Modular arithmetic. I would call it niether "shortcut" nor "trick", but rather a set of tools and techniques which you may want to learn properly, rather than trying to interpolate them from exercise solutions asked in a forum.

Comment: Plz help me with atleast something to solve these sort of ques(eg. given in ques) at least

Comment: It's not like the area of the trapezium, for which I can give you the handy-dandy formula. As far as I'm concerned, explaining these to you is tantamount to giving you the basics of modular arithmetic or, at least, cutting through the details in a way that would actively prevent you from grasping the basics. Either way, I personally don't see a reason to do it, since it takes a considerable effort of writing and explanation, while the outcome would be rather underwhelming. I suggest you [learn it on your own](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/628254/book-on-modular-arithmetic).